# Prove that $\phi (2^n-1)$ is a multiple of $n$ for any $n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

Prove that $\phi (2^n-1)$ is a multiple of $n$ for any $n>1$.

I'm not really sure how to start this proof.

Comment: But basically, $2^n\equiv 1\pmod{2^n-1}$. Can $2^m\equiv 1\pmod{2^n-1}$ for any  $m<n$?